# Connect Symfony to an read-only database

Tags: database, symfony

I have to connect a read-only database using symfony for specific user because for not change any scheme of  application database.

In specially deny of write new tables like **doctrine_migration_versions**

PHP 8.0
Symfony 6.0.0

Is this possible?

Comment: I think it's more related to your database than to symfony you can create a user with read only privelage to your database, he can't change the schema with new tables

Comment: Don't use migrations then? Not sure what Symfony has to do with this.

Comment: Yes user will have read-only privilege, and yes the web application should not use migration because he is only guest and should not damage database.